# interpreting return in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

Given the following HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li><strong>list</strong> item 1 - one strong tag</li>
  <li><strong>list</strong> item <strong>2</strong> -
    two <span>strong tags</span></li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
</ul>
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
$( "li" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return $( "strong", this ).length === 1; //this line
  })
    .css( "background-color", "red" );
```

It is really hard to understand what the return statement is doing here. Does the return statement really mean the following?

```
if ($( "strong", this ).length === 1){
      return true ;
}else {
     return false ; 
}
```

Is my interpretation correct?

I found this example on the jQuery docs page and went through a few SO post but nothing was really resolving my question.

I created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tjydherk/)

EDIT : Also a supplementary question :

so given the same block of code again :

```
$( "li" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return $( "strong", this ).length === 1; //this line
  })
    .css( "background-color", "red" );
```

if the following statement :

```
return $( "strong", this ).length === 1; //this line
```

returns false , then the next block of code that's "chained" using Jquery Chaining I.E .

```
.css( "background-color", "red" );
```

will not execute . am i right ?

Comment: your interpretation is correct

Comment: Wow Thanks @ArunPJohny , i have been on this for a while now . :)

Comment: It returns `$( "strong", this ).length === 1`. That's an expression which is evaluated either to `true` or `false`. So your interpretation is somewhat correct in that essentially these are the same. But there is a complexity difference. Using `if` adds redundant code that has to be evaluated.

Comment: @freakish Thanks . justed edited my question slightly with another supplementary question .

Comment: @Tenali_raman Not quite. `.filter` function reduces `$("li")` element **only** to those that pass your function test. So if for a particular element `$("strong", this).length === 1` is `true` then `.css` will be applied to it. Otherwise it will be not. Note the ordering though. First filtering happens on **all** elements and **then** `.css` is applied to the result.

Comment: @freakish Thank you ! one last question , why the parameter "index" ?? I.E on the line  .filter(function( index )  , What value is it holding or passing ?? i can't quite understand .

Comment: @Tenali_raman `$( "li" )` actually returns a list of all elements that match the selector, i.e. a list of all `li` tags. Now when you do `.filter` it goes through each element in the order it finds it in HTML. The `index` variable is a current index of the element you are looking at. For example with your HTML element `<li>list item 4</li>` would have `index == 3` because it is 4th `li` tag (note that indexes start from `0`).

Comment: @freakish Fantastic ! I totally did't understand that part , but now i do , thaks a TON! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`===` is a logical operator so it return a bool value
So you can do

```
return $( "strong", this ).length === 1;
```

instead of

```
if($( "strong", this ).length === 1){
    return true;
}else{
     return false;
}
```

For the edit:

the `filter` method is used to select a list of "li" that you want.

so i think that if the `$( "strong", this ).length === 1` is false, the current `this` `li` will not be in the list.
Then it will execute the `css` method on all `li` that are in the list.

Comment: i edited my question with a supplementary question , can u edit ur answer and i'll accept it . Thanks . Sorry for the trouble , but Jquery is pretty confusing to me .